# EXTJS: change visited link

Tags: html, css, extjs, hyperlink, anchor

I am new to ExtJS.

We are using ExtJs client side and struts, spring at server side. In our application all links used to appear in color blue. Somehow due to few changes the visited links are unable to change to different color.

Can someone suggest me a way to change visited links color?

Answer (score 2):

Apply css

```
a:visited
{
     color : red !important
}
```

Somewhere a rogue css style for a:visited has been applied. You need to find it and remove it. Until then the above css can be used. The `!important` will give this higher priority unless the rogue css style also has the `!important` applied to it.